# How to save a data.frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I made a data.frame in R that is not very big, but it takes quite some time to build. I would to save it as a file, which I can than again open in R?

Answer (score 217, accepted):

There are several ways. One way is to use `save()` to save the exact object. e.g. for data frame `foo`:

```
save(foo,file="data.Rda")
```

Then load it with:

```
load("data.Rda")
```

You could also use `write.table()` or something like that to save the table in plain text, or `dput()` to obtain R code to reproduce the table.

Comment: There is also `dump` and files created would be `source()`-ed, although the `help(dump)` page says `save` is "safer".

Comment: I always prefer storing data in plain text, so I'd prefer `dump()` over `save()`, and `write.table()` over `dump()`

Comment: Am I correct that write.table won't preserve things like having set up a column of 0's and 1's as a factor, but that `save()` / `load()` will? If so, that's something to take into account as well. I typically have a section of processing some .csv files and once I get them where I like them, I prefer to save them so I don't have to re-run that code every time I re-visit my project. So, preserving that work/tweaks to the structure is important to consider.

Comment: Yes. `dump()` also saves the structure. The nice thing about `write.table` is that it writes tables in a way many software can import.

Comment: This saves rather more than just the dataframe. See ``saveRDS`` to save a dataframe without its name (dhendrickson has an answer on that).

Answer (score 113):

If you are only saving a single object (your data frame), you could also use `saveRDS`.
To save:

```
saveRDS(foo, file="data.Rda")
```

Then read it with:

```
bar <- readRDS(file="data.Rda")
```

The difference between `saveRDS` and `save` is that in the former only one object can be saved and the name of the object is not forced to be the same after you load it.

Answer (score 7):

If you have a data frame named `df`, you can simply export it to same directory with:

```
write.csv(df, "output.csv", row.names=FALSE, quote=FALSE)
```

credit to: Peter and Ilja, UMCG, the Netherlands.