# Simplified dput() in R

Tags: r, formatting

I miss a way to add data to an SO answer in a transparent manner. My experience is that the `structure` object from `dput()` at times confuses inexperienced users unnecessary. I do however not have the patience to copy/paste it into a simple data frame each time and would like to automate it. Something similar to `dput()`, but in a simplified version.

Say I by copy/pasting and some other hos have data like this,

```
Df <- data.frame(A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
                 B = c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"),
                 C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA))
```

looks like this,

```
Df
#>   A    B  C
#> 1 2    A  1
#> 2 2    G  3
#> 3 2    N  5
#> 4 6 <NA> NA
#> 5 7    L NA
#> 6 8    L NA
```

Within one integer, one factor and one numeric vector,

```
str(Df)
#> 'data.frame':    6 obs. of  3 variables:
#>  $ A: num  2 2 2 6 7 8
#>  $ B: Factor w/ 4 levels "A","G","L","N": 1 2 4 NA 3 3
#>  $ C: int  1 3 5 NA NA NA
```

Now, I would like to share this on SO, but I do not always have the *orginal* data frame it came from. More often than not I `pipe()` it in form SO and the only way I know to get it out is `dput()`. Like,

```
dput(Df)
#> structure(list(A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8), B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 
#> 4L, NA, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "G", "L", "N"), class = "factor"), 
#> C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA)), .Names = c("A", "B", "C"), row.names = c(NA, 
#> -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

but, as I said at the top, these `structure`s can look quite confusing. For that reason I am looking for a way to compress `dput()`'s output in some way. I imagine an output that looks something like this,

```
dput_small(Df)
#> data.frame(A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8), B = c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"),
#> C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA))
```

Is that possible? I realize there's other classes, like `lists`, `tbl`, `tbl_df`, etc.

Comment: We could *dput* to a file, then *readLines* and do some *regex*ing.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

*Edit: leaving the older solution at the bottom because it got a bounty and many votes but proposing an improved answer*

You can use the [{constructive} package](https://github.com/cynkra/constructive) :

```r
# install.packages("constructive")
# or dev version:
# remotes::install_github("cynkra/constructive")
Df <- data.frame(A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
                 B = c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"),
                 C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA))

constructive::construct(Df)
#> data.frame(
#>   A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
#>   B = c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"),
#>   C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA)
#> )
```

It has custom constructors to many common classes so it should be able to reproduce most objects faithfully in a human readable way.

---

*Old solution:*

> **3 solutions :**
>
> - a wrapper around `dput` (handles standard `data.frames`, `tibbles` and `lists`)
> - a `read.table` solution (for `data.frames`)
> - a `tibble::tribble` solution (for `data.frames`, returning a `tibble`)
>
> All include `n` and `random` parameter which allow one to dput only the head of the data or sample it on the fly.

```
dput_small1(Df)
# Df <- data.frame(
#   A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
#   B = structure(c(1L, 2L, 4L, NA, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("A", "G", "L", 
#     "N"), class = "factor"),
#   C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA) ,
#   stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

dput_small2(Df,stringsAsFactors=TRUE)
# Df <- read.table(sep="\t", text="
#   A   B   C
#   2   A    1
#   2   G    3
#   2   N    5
#   6   NA  NA
#   7   L   NA
#   8   L   NA", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=TRUE)

dput_small3(Df)
# Df <- tibble::tribble(
#   ~A, ~B, ~C,
#   2,           "A",          1L,
#   2,           "G",          3L,
#   2,           "N",          5L,
#   6, NA_character_, NA_integer_,
#   7,           "L", NA_integer_,
#   8,           "L", NA_integer_
# )
# Df$B <- factor(Df$B)
```

## Wrapper around `dput`

This option that gives an output very close to the one proposed in the question. It's quite general because it's actually wrapped around `dput`, but applied separately on columns.

`multiline` means *'keep dput's default output laid out into multiple lines'*.

```
dput_small1<- function(x,
                       name=as.character(substitute(x)),
                       multiline = TRUE,
                       n=if ('list' %in% class(x)) length(x) else nrow(x),
                       random=FALSE,
                       seed = 1){
  name
  if('tbl_df' %in% class(x)) create_fun <- "tibble::tibble" else
    if('list' %in% class(x)) create_fun <- "list" else
      if('data.table' %in% class(x)) create_fun <- "data.table::data.table" else
        create_fun <- "data.frame"
    
    if(random) {
      set.seed(seed)
      if(create_fun == "list") x <- x[sample(1:length(x),n)] else 
        x <- x[sample(1:nrow(x),n),]
    } else {
      x <- head(x,n)
    }
    
    line_sep <- if (multiline) "\n    " else ""
    cat(sep='',name," <- ",create_fun,"(\n  ",
        paste0(unlist(
          Map(function(item,nm) paste0(nm,if(nm=="") "" else " = ",paste(capture.output(dput(item)),collapse=line_sep)),
              x,if(is.null(names(x))) rep("",length(x)) else names(x))),
          collapse=",\n  "),
        if(create_fun == "data.frame") ",\n  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)" else "\n)")
}

dput_small1(list(1,2,c=3,d=4),"my_list",random=TRUE,n=3)
# my_list <- list(
#   2,
#   d = 4,
#   c = 3
# )
```

## `read.table` solution

For `data.frames` I find it comfortable however to have the input in a more explicit/tabular format.

This can be reached using `read.table`, then reformatting automatically the type of columns that `read.table` wouldn't get right. Not as general as first solution but will work smoothly for 95% of the cases found on `SO`.

```
dput_small2 <- function(df,
                        name=as.character(substitute(df)),
                        sep='\t',
                        header=TRUE,
                        stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
                        n= nrow(df),
                        random=FALSE,
                        seed = 1){
    name
    if(random) {
      set.seed(seed)
      df <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),n),]
    } else {
      df <- head(df,n)
    }
  cat(sep='',name,' <- read.table(sep="',sub('\t','\\\\t',sep),'", text="\n  ',
      paste(colnames(df),collapse=sep))
  df <- head(df,n)
  apply(df,1,function(x) cat(sep='','\n  ',paste(x,collapse=sep)))
  cat(sep='','", header=',header,', stringsAsFactors=',stringsAsFactors,')')
  
  sapply(names(df), function(x){
    if(is.character(df[[x]]) & suppressWarnings(identical(as.character(as.numeric(df[[x]])),df[[x]]))){ # if it's a character column containing numbers
      cat(sep='','\n',name,'$',x,' <- as.character(', name,'$',x,')')
    } else if(is.factor(df[[x]]) & !stringsAsFactors) { # if it's a factor and conversion is not automated
      cat(sep='','\n',name,'$',x,' <- factor(', name,'$',x,')')
    } else if(inherits(df[[x]], "POSIXct")){
      cat(sep='','\n',name,'$',x,' <- as.POSIXct(', name,'$',x,')')
    } else if(inherits(df[[x]], "Date")){
      cat(sep='','\n',name,'$',x,' <- as.Date(', name,'$',x,')')
    }})
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

**Simplest case**

```
dput_small2(iris,n=6)
```

will print:

```
iris <- read.table(sep="\t", text="
  Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length    Petal.Width Species
  5.1   3.5 1.4 0.2  setosa
  4.9   3.0 1.4 0.2  setosa
  4.7   3.2 1.3 0.2  setosa
  4.6   3.1 1.5 0.2  setosa
  5.0   3.6 1.4 0.2  setosa
  5.4   3.9 1.7 0.4  setosa", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

which in turn when executed will return :

```
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4  setosa

str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 6 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4
# $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9
# $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7
# $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4
# $ Species     : chr  " setosa" " setosa" " setosa" " setosa" ...
```

**more complex**

dummy data:

```
test <- data.frame(a=1:5,
                   b=as.character(6:10),
                   c=letters[1:5],
                   d=factor(letters[6:10]),
                   e=Sys.time()+(1:5),
                   stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This:

```
dput_small2(test,'df2')
```

will print:

```
df2 <- read.table(sep="\t", text="
  a b   c   d   e
  1 6   a   f   2018-02-15 11:53:17
  2 7   b   g   2018-02-15 11:53:18
  3 8   c   h   2018-02-15 11:53:19
  4 9   d   i   2018-02-15 11:53:20
  5 10  e   j   2018-02-15 11:53:21", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df2$b <- as.character(df2$b)
df2$d <- factor(df2$d)
df2$e <- as.POSIXct(df2$e)
```

which in turn when executed will return :

```
#   a  b c d                   e
# 1 1  6 a f 2018-02-15 11:53:17
# 2 2  7 b g 2018-02-15 11:53:18
# 3 3  8 c h 2018-02-15 11:53:19
# 4 4  9 d i 2018-02-15 11:53:20
# 5 5 10 e j 2018-02-15 11:53:21

str(df2)    
# 'data.frame': 5 obs. of  5 variables:
# $ a: int  1 2 3 4 5
# $ b: chr  "6" "7" "8" "9" ...
# $ c: chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
# $ d: Factor w/ 5 levels "f","g","h","i",..: 1 2 3 4 5
# $ e: POSIXct, format: "2018-02-15 11:53:17" "2018-02-15 11:53:18" "2018-02-15 11:53:19" "2018-02-15 11:53:20" ...

all.equal(df2,test)
# [1] "Component “e”: Mean absolute difference: 0.4574251" # only some rounding error
```

## `tribble` solution

The `read.table` option is very readable but not very general. with `tribble` pretty much any data type can be handled (though factors need adhoc fixing).

This solution isn't so useful for OP's example but is great for list columns (see example below). To make use of the output, library `tibble` is required.

Just as my first solution, it's a wrapper around `dput`, but instead of 'dputting' columns, i'm 'dputting' elements.

```
dput_small3 <- function(df,
                        name=as.character(substitute(df)),
                        n= nrow(df),
                        random=FALSE,
                        seed = 1){
  name
  if(random) {
    set.seed(seed)
    df <- df[sample(1:nrow(df),n),]
  } else {
    df <- head(df,n)
  }
  df1 <- lapply(df,function(col) if(is.factor(col)) as.character(col) else col)
  dputs   <- sapply(df1,function(col){
    col_dputs <- sapply(col,function(elt) paste(capture.output(dput(elt)),collapse=""))
    max_char <- max(nchar(unlist(col_dputs)))
    sapply(col_dputs,function(elt) paste(c(rep(" ",max_char-nchar(elt)),elt),collapse=""))
  })
  lines   <- paste(apply(dputs,1,paste,collapse=", "),collapse=",\n  ")
  output  <- paste0(name," <- tibble::tribble(\n  ",
                    paste0("~",names(df),collapse=", "),
                    ",\n  ",lines,"\n)")
  cat(output)
  sapply(names(df), function(x) if(is.factor(df[[x]])) cat(sep='','\n',name,'$',x,' <- factor(', name,'$',x,')'))
  invisible(NULL)
}

dput_small3(dplyr::starwars[c(1:3,11)],"sw",n=6,random=TRUE)
# sw <- tibble::tribble(
#   ~name, ~height, ~mass, ~films,
#   "Lando Calrissian", 177L,       79,                     c("Return of the Jedi", "The Empire Strikes Back"),
#      "Finis Valorum", 170L, NA_real_,                                                   "The Phantom Menace",
#       "Ki-Adi-Mundi", 198L,       82, c("Attack of the Clones", "The Phantom Menace", "Revenge of the Sith"),
#           "Grievous", 216L,      159,                                                  "Revenge of the Sith",
#     "Wedge Antilles", 170L,       77,       c("Return of the Jedi", "The Empire Strikes Back", "A New Hope"),
#         "Wat Tambor", 193L,       48,                                                 "Attack of the Clones"
# )
```

Comment: Nice solutions... It would be nice to have also the possibility to take a random sample of the lines rather than the first n lines (for example for the iris dataset...). Easy to do for example with a `sample = NULL` function argument and then `if(!is.null(sample)) {
        df <- df[sample(1:nrow(df), sample),]
    } else {
        df <- head(df,n)
    }` In the function.

Comment: Done, I implemented the `head` and `sample` features for both solutions, and made the first solution handle `lists` and `tibbles`.

Comment: I feel like this neat code belong to some package in the [tag:tidyverse]. Maybe [David Robinson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/712603/david-robinson) would be up for adding this to his [stackr](https://github.com/dgrtwo/stackr) package or something like it.

Comment: `tidyverse` made me think of `tibble::tribble` so I added a third solution, and support for `data.table` in the first one

Answer (score 23):

The package [`datapasta`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/datapasta/vignettes/how-to-datapasta.html) won't always work perfectly as it currently doesn't support all types, but it is clean and easy, i.e.,

```
# install.packages(c("datapasta"), dependencies = TRUE)    
datapasta::dpasta(Df)
#> data.frame(
#>            A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
#>            C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA),
#>            B = as.factor(c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"))
#> )
```

Comment: there's also datapasta::dmdclip() which will give you the same output on the clipboard, with each line lead by 4 spaces. ;)

Comment: Very interesting. I did not know about the [tag:datapasta] package. Thanks!

Comment: nice package and nice name

Comment: Out of topic, but is it possible to copy the ouptput directly to the clipboard?

Comment: @Julien  --> sure (with `datapasta::dmdclip()`)

Answer (score 11):

You could simply write to a compressed connection.

```
gz <- gzfile("foo.gz", open="wt")
dput(Df, gz)
close(gz)
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this answer. Could you possibly show what kinda output this provide?

Comment: Your original question (nearly 5 years ago!) said, "I would like `dput()` to compress the output in some way."  My answer compresses the output using standard `gzip` compression.  It was not clear that by "compress in some way", you meant, "change the text representation to be more understandable by humans."

Comment: Good point! Excellent point! It was after thinking about the original wording that I decided to reword it and put a bounty, I think five years ago I was too intimidated to ask for clarification from you. Regardless, what I meant to say (also then) was that I am looking for a clearer output to share structures on SO (and elsewhere). Thanks you for your feedback!

Comment: I apologize fro the unclear wording when I initially posted this.

Answer (score 11):

We could set *control* to *NULL* to simplify:

```
dput(Df, control = NULL)
# list(A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8), B = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 9), C = c(1, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA))
```

Then wrap it with *data.frame*:

```
data.frame(dput(Df, control = NULL))
```

---

**Edit:** To avoid factor columns getting converted to numbers, we could convert them to character before calling dput:

```
dput_small <- function(d){
  ix <- sapply(d, is.factor)
  d[ix] <- lapply(d[ix], as.character)
  dput(d, control = NULL)
  }
```

Comment: Interesting. I did look at this. This was actually what made me add a factor to the object. I apologize for not doing that from the start.

Comment: How do you share data you have in R on SO? Accept `dput()`'s output at looks a bit clunky?

Comment: @EricFail If small data, then use dput, if bigger I use `df1 <- read.table(text = "my delimited data")` but with read.table you will lose the attributes, so need to check the output if same as intended.

Comment: @EricFail see edit, also there is a [reprex](http://reprex.tidyverse.org/) package.

Comment: Very nice indeed. I wasen't aware of the [tag:reprex] package. It should have a function like this.

Comment: @EricFail you could [submit issue at GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex/issues)

Comment: Good point. I will see what comes up here in the next days and think about submitting something to [tag:reprex]. I imagine a [tag:reprex] function also would have to be compatible with `tbl`, `tbl_df`, `grouped_df` and maybe more.

Comment: The tidyverse website advises using `dput` with `head` or `sample` http://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex.html

Comment: Really cool and simple solution ! You could add `cat("d <- as.data.frame(")` before `dput(d, control = NULL)` and  `cat(")")` just after this line to make the output on the console copy/paste ready !

Answer (score 3):

Generally a large `dput` is difficult to cope with, on SO or otherwise.  Instead you can just save the structure directly to an `Rda` file:

```
save(Df, file='foo.Rda')
```

And read it back in:

```
load('foo.Rda')
```

See this question for a little more info and credit where credit is due: [How to save a data.frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345759/how-to-save-a-data-frame-in-r)

You could also look at the `sink` function...

If I've missed the purpose of your question, please feel free to expand on the reasons why `dput` is the only mechanism for you.

Answer (score 3):

It might be worth mentioning `memCompress` and `memDecompress` here. For in-memory objects, it can reduce the size of large objects by compressing them as specified.  And the latter reverses the compression.  They're actually quite useful for package objects.

```
sum(nchar(dput(DF)))
# [1] 64
( mDF <- memCompress(as.character(DF)) )
# [1] 78 9c 4b d6 30 d2 51 80 20 33 1d 05 73 1d 05 0b 4d ae 64 0d 3f 47 1d 05 64 0c 14 b7 04 89 1b ea 28 18 eb 28 98 22 4b 6a 02 00 a8 ba 0c d2
length(mDF)
# [1] 46
cat(mdDF <- memDecompress(mDF, "gzip", TRUE))
# c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8)
# c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 7, 9)
# c(1, 3, 5, NA, NA, NA)
nchar(mdDF)
# [1] 66
```

I haven't quite determined if the data frame can be reassembled easily, but I'm sure it can be.

Comment: Thanks, interesting. I hope you realized I asked this question in Sep '13. However, I do appreciate your response.

Comment: I did.  I came across this post while searching for something else and it's a good question. Plus I've been using `memCompress` with some package data so I thought I'd share.

Comment: I appreciate you took the time to share and thanks for the nice words.

Answer (score 3):

There is also the [`read.so`](https://github.com/alistaire47/read.so) package, which I really like, in particular to *read* SO data.
It works for tibbles as well.

```r
#devtools::install_github("alistaire47/read.so")
Df <- data.frame(A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
                 B = c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"),
                 C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA))

read.so::write.so(Df)

#> Df <- data.frame(
#>   A = c(2, 2, 2, 6, 7, 8),
#>   B = c("A", "G", "N", NA, "L", "L"),
#>   C = c(1L, 3L, 5L, NA, NA, NA)
#> )
```