# What's the difference between is and inherits?

Tags: r, inheritance, r-faq

If I want to check whether a variable inherits from some class, I can either use [`is`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/is) or [`inherits`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/inherits).

```
class(letters)
## [1] "character"
is(letters, "character")
## [1] TRUE
inherits(letters, "character")
## [1] TRUE
```

Is there a preference for which one I should use, and do they ever return different values?

Comment: @Richie as you both asked and answered this question, can you include `"character" %in% class(letters)` to your question/answer? My understanding given this post is that it's equivalent to inherits, just slower, but i'm not sure.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Yes, that also works, though the intention of the code is less clear, so I'm not sure when you'd want to use it.

Comment: I used it in this answer for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746456/simplified-dput-in-r . `is.list(iris)` is `TRUE` but `"list" %in% class(iris)` and `inherits(iris,"list")` are `FALSE`, which is useful to distinguish data.frames from lists. Should I understand, to hammer the nail, the 2 latter are indeed equivalent and that you recommend `inherits` in all cases ? Btw your nice datacamp course brought me here.

Answer (score 14):

Short version:

Use `inherits`, but be careful with numbers and S4 classes.

---

Longer version:

From the See Also section of the `is` help page:

> inherits is nearly always equivalent to is, both for S4 and non-S4
>   objects, and is somewhat faster. The non-equivalence applies to
>   classes that have conditional superclasses, with a non-trivial test=
>   in the relation (not common and discouraged): for these, is tests for
>   the relation but inherits by definition ignores conditional
>   inheritance for S4 objects.

From the Formal Classes section of the `inherits` help page:

> The analogue of inherits for formal classes is is. The two functions
>   behave consistently with one exception: S4 classes can have
>   conditional inheritance, with an explicit test. In this case, is will
>   test the condition, but inherits ignores all conditional superclasses.

So they mostly return the same thing, but `inherits` is faster, so it should be the default choice in most cases.  (As mentioned by Konrad, `is` also requires that the `methods` package is loaded, which may make it unsuitable for performance sensitive uses of [`Rscript`](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/utils/Rscript).)

The values can differ if you are using S4 classes with conditional inheritance, but this is [not recommended](http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/methods/Methods) (see "Method Selection and Dispatch: Details" section), which means that it is hopefully rare.

The most obvious place where the two functions differ is when checking if integers are numeric.

```
class(1L)
## [1] "integer"
is.numeric(1L)
## [1] TRUE
is(1L, "numeric")
## [1] TRUE
inherits(1L, "numeric")
## [1] FALSE
```

Comment: OK, so can you explain **why** integers don't "inherit" , whereas floats do:  Rgames> class(1.4)
[1] "numeric"
Rgames> is.numeric(1.4)
[1] TRUE
Rgames> inherits(1.4,'numeric')
[1] TRUE
Rgames> is(1.4,'numeric')
[1] TRUE

Comment: I think this may be related to the fact that numeric objects have an *implicit* class only: from `?class`, `If the object does not have a class attribute, it has an implicit class, ‘"matrix"’, ‘"array"’ or the result of ‘mode(x)’ (except that integer vectors have implicit class ‘"integer"’).` I can imagine (??) that `is` looks at implicit classes and `inherits` doesn't ... ?

Comment: I remember overhearing a comment of high-R subjects calling this an "infelicity".

Comment: Another, quite crucial, difference is that `is` is in package `methods` which is by default not loaded when running `Rscript` (because it’s slow to load). `inherits`, by contrast, is from `base` and therefore readily available in R script programs.

Answer (score 1):

Besides `is()` and `inherits()` we can also test objects with `is.*()` for a certain type. Those three function can return different results. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40171527/11359310) answer I did the following

- Created numerous R objects of different types
- Extracted the type of those objects using `storage.mode()`, `mode()`, `typeof()` and `class()`.
- Tested the objects whether they are of the returned types using `is()`, `inherits()` and `is.*()`.

Here is a small example of the three steps above:

```
# Get object classes withs torage.mode(), mode(), typeof() and class().
obj <- logical()
(types <- c(storage.mode= storage.mode(obj),
            mode= mode(obj),
            type= typeof(obj),
            class= class(obj)))
storage.mode         mode         type        class
    "double"    "numeric"     "double"    "numeric"

# Test returned types with is, inhertis and is.*.
> is(obj, "double"); is(obj, "numeric")
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
> inherits(obj, "double"); inherits(obj, "numeric")
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
> is.double(obj); is.numeric(obj)
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
```

Now we do this for a bunch of object types with the following code:

```
# Generate objects of different types.
library(xml2)
setClass("dummy", representation(x="numeric", y="numeric"))
obj <- list(
  "logical vector" = logical(),
  "integer vector" = integer(),
  "numeric vector" = numeric(),
  "complex vector" = complex(),
  "character vector" = character(),
  "raw vector" = raw(),
  "factor" = factor(),
  "logical matrix" = matrix(logical()),
  "numeric matrix" = matrix(numeric()),
  "logical array" = array(logical(8), c(2, 2, 2)),
  "numeric array" = array(numeric(8), c(2, 2, 2)),
  "list" = list(),
  "pairlist" = .Options,
  "data frame" = data.frame(),
  "closure function" = identity,
  "builtin function" = `+`,
  "special function" = `if`,
  "environment" = new.env(),
  "null" = NULL,
  "formula" = y ~ x,
  "expression" = expression(),
  "call" = call("identity"),
  "name" = as.name("x"),
  #"paren in expression" = expression((1))[[1]], # Code fails with this
  #"brace in expression" = expression({1})[[1]], # Code fails with this
  "S3 lm object" = lm(dist ~ speed, cars),
  "S4 dummy object" = new("dummy", x = 1:10, y = rnorm(10)),
  "external pointer" = read_xml("<foo><bar /></foo>")$node
  )

# Extract types and test them.
res <- do.call("rbind.data.frame", Map(function(x, name){
  types <- c(storage.mode= storage.mode(x),
                mode= mode(x),
                type= typeof(x),
                class= class(x))
  data.frame("object"= name,
             "extract_method"= names(types),
             "extract_result"= types,
             "inherits"= sapply(types, function(i) inherits(x, i)),
             "is"= sapply(types, function(i) is(x, i)),
             "is.type"= sapply(types, function(i) eval(parse(text= paste0("tryCatch({is.", i, "(x)}, error= function(e){'is.", i, "() does not exist'})"))))
  )}, obj, names(obj)))
rownames(res) <- 1:nrow(res)
res <- res[order(res$extract_method), ]
```

We can get a few insights from the results `res`. For example, we can loow were `is.()` does not return same as `inherits()`:

```
> res[res$inherits != res$is, ]
           object extract_method extract_result inherits   is is.type
6  integer vector           mode        numeric    FALSE TRUE TRUE
87           call   storage.mode       language    FALSE TRUE TRUE
89           call           type       language    FALSE TRUE TRUE
```

Of course the results show much more, e.g. we can see where `inherits()` returns `FALSE` on types that where returned of one of the three extraction methods and so on. I left this out here. In fact, I think my answer is much broader since it takes into account both, differences in extraction *and* test of object type. After reading quite some time about object types I arrived at the code above and wanted to share it. However, using `res[res$inherits != res$is, ]` soly answers the question.