# R function that accepts an object and returns the code necessary to generate that object in the R interpreter

Tags: r

Is there an R function that accepts an R object and returns code that can be run to generate that object?

Example

When passed the first 5 rows of the `iris` dataframe

```
iris
# Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species
# 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2  setosa
# 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2  setosa
# 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2  setosa
# 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2  setosa
```

The function would generate the following string like so:

```
string <- "data.frame(\"Sepal.Length\"=as.numeric(c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0)), \"Sepal.Width\"=as.numeric(c(3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6)), \"Petal.Length\"=as.numeric(c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4)), \"Petal.Width\"=as.numeric(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)), \"Species\"=as.factor(c(\"setosa\", \"setosa\", \"setosa\", \"setosa\", \"setosa\")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)"
```

Then calling `cat(string)` would print to console the exact code necessary to generate the object (in this case, a dataframe)

```
data.frame("Sepal.Length"=as.numeric(c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5.0)), "Sepal.Width"=as.numeric(c(3.5, 3.0, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6)), "Petal.Length"=as.numeric(c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4)), "Petal.Width"=as.numeric(c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)), "Species"=as.factor(c("setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa", "setosa")), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Does such a function exist?

Comment: you can use `dput`. It would give you exact code to create the object passed. `dput(iris[1:5, ])`

Comment: Relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18746456/simplified-dput-in-r

Comment: I'm voting to reopen this question. There's a great answer (and additional answer in the comment above, but there's still no reason for it to be closed. Also, the close reason is for 'seeking recommendations for books, tools' but it doesn't do that at all, it asks for R code/function(s) like every other [R] tag question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for `dput`.

For example, for 1st 5 rows of `iris`, you could do

```
dput(iris[1:5,])

#structure(list(Sepal.Length = c(5.1, 4.9, 4.7, 4.6, 5), Sepal.Width = c(3.5, 
#3, 3.2, 3.1, 3.6), Petal.Length = c(1.4, 1.4, 1.3, 1.5, 1.4), 
#    Petal.Width = c(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2), Species = structure(c(1L, 
#    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("setosa", "versicolor", "virginica"
#    ), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", 
#"Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species"), row.names = c(NA, 
#5L), class = "data.frame")
```

and now you could use the same code to recreate the object again.

Another example,

```
x <- c(3, 4, 1, 2)
dput(x)
#c(3, 4, 1, 2)
```

Comment: From R documentation: "dput {base} - Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the object.". I had not come across this function before. It is exactly what I am after! Thank you