# Paste into RStudio script pane without auto formatting without turning off auto indent?

Tags: r, rstudio, dput

Is there any way to paste into the RStudio script pane *without* having the code auto indent itself, AND without turning off the auto indent feature?

#### Example

The output of `dput(iris)` looks organised in the console, but spreads **very wide** when pasted into the script pane. This is not great for code readability, and also for other things like copy/pasting into Stack Overflow or other code editors

In **console**:

[image]

After pasting into **script pane**:

[image]

#### Notes

- Similar question and use cases have been [put on the RStudio blog](https://community.rstudio.com/t/is-it-possible-to-prevent-rstudio-from-auto-formatting-when-copying-and-pasting-the-output-from-dput/6161/10), but the main solution seems to be to turn auto indent off in the Tools menu, but I cannot find a temporary solution suitable for intermittent pasting

Comment: As it is about "copy/pasting into Stack Overflow", see related (Possible duplicate) post? https://stackoverflow.com/q/18746456/680068