# How can I read an input file into shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

My shiny app is based on a single .csv file for its data. So I need to input the data on startup. That way if someone opens the app on their system, the result is is shown by the app right way. How can I do this?

Comment: There's an example here how to save the data 'permanetly'
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345759/how-to-save-a-data-frame-in-r
alternatively you can probably write it to the global environment with <<-

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a few options here. I assume you know how to read the file into R using `read.csv` or something similar.

You can put the input the `read.csv` in one of three places:

**1) Globlal.r:**  If you have a `global.r` file you can use `read.csv` there and the data will be directly available to both the `ui` and the `server` functions. Typically you do not need to do this but it is an option.

For the next two options the data will be directly available to the `server` side, but must be passed to the `ui` side through one of the `render` functions.

**2)Server.r but NOT in shinyServer:** In this case the `read.csv` is located in `server.r` file but outside of the `shinyServer()` function. The file will be read in one time per session and will not change. This is a common place to read in data.

**3) Server.r and in shinyServer:** In this case the `read.csv` is part of the`shinySever()` function. This is a good place to read the data if you want some degree of reactivity to be involved. For example, if the user chooses which data to input or if the data file is constantly updating (stock prices maybe) and you want to check the data file periodically for updates while the user is working.

**Note:** You also need to consider where the data is stored. You can put it in a subdirectory of your app directory and then read it is using a relative (not absolute) path. This is helpful if you are testing your app on your desktop, but are going to deploy it elsewhere and don't wish to rewrite the code to take the new directory structure into account.