# How to save a data frame in R

Tags: r, save, dataframe

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345759/how-to-save-a-data-frame-in-r), you can save a data frame "foo" in R with the save() function as follows:

```
save(foo,file="data.Rda")
```

Here is data frame "df":

```
> str(df)
'data.frame':   1254 obs. of  2 variables
$ text : chr  "RT @SchmittySays: I love this 1st grade #science teacher from #Duluth http://t.co/HWDYFnIyqV  #NSTA15 #AlbertEinstein #inspirat"| __truncated__ "RT @KVernonBHS: @smrtgrls would love Stellar Girls. Empowering female scientists rocks! #NSTA15 http://t.co/1ZU0yjVF67" "RT @leducmills: Leaving #SXSWedu to go straight to #NSTA15. There should be some sort of arbitrary conference-hopper social med"| __truncated__ "RT @KRScienceLady: Congrats to a wonderful colleague who  helped #ngss Bcome reality, Stephen Pruitt, Distinguished Service to "| __truncated__ ...
$ group: Factor w/ 2 levels "narst","nsta": 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ...
```

It seems to save fine:

```
> save(df, file = "~/downloads/df.Rda")
```

But it turns out only the name of the object saved:

```
> df1 <- load("~/downloads/df.Rda")
> str(df1)
chr "df"
```

I tried the saveRDS() function suggested in another answer to the same question referenced above which worked fine, but I'd like to know why save() isn't working.

Comment: your problem is with the `load` function. Instead of `df <- load("~/downloads/df.Rda")`, use `load("~/downloads/df.Rda")`

Comment: @Alex has it - you don't need to assign when doing `load`, it will just create the object you saved in the `parent.frame()` environment - in this case the global workspace. The reason why you get `"df"` in text returned is because, as `?load` says, the function returns: `A character vector of the names of objects created, invisibly.` The saved data should still have been loaded into `df` though.

Comment: Is there a smart way to assign while loading though? This always gets me as well. Thanks for the explanation @thelatemail.

Comment: @Alex - maybe - `tmpenv <- new.env(); load("df.Rda",envir=tmpenv); newdf <- tmpenv[["df"]]` or something similar.

Comment: Other useful suggestions via: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[r]+load+environment+is%3Aanswer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this question here: [R data formats: RData, Rda, Rds etc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21370132/r-data-formats-rdata-rda-rds-etc).

When loading an `.rda` object, you are going to load all objects with their original names to the global environment. You can't assign objects to new names using `load` as you tried to do.

If you want to save objects that can be loaded with different names later, then you should use the `.rds` format (`saveRDS` and `readRDS`). If you want to save more than one object in a `.rds` file, the simplest solution is to put all of them on a list and save only the list. If after reading the `.rds` you want to put the objects of the list in the global environment, you can use `list2env`.